# Using Undercover with ScalaTest and Maven

Tags: scala, code-coverage

I'm having major problems getting [Undercover](http://code.google.com/p/undercover/) to work using Maven

I'm using ScalaTest for unit tests and this is working perfectly
When I run Undercover though it simply creates empty files

I think it's probably a problem with the configuration in my pom.xml (but the documentation for Undercover is a little sketchy)

Help :)
Thanks
T

Answer (score 0):

At one point I inquired about [Emma](http://emma.sourceforge.net/) on a Scala mailing list, and I was told that by some that they had more success with [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/). You might want to try that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Up to what stage is this "working correctly", given that empty files are being produced?

Do you have a sample project/POM that demonstrates the problem?